# The Google Cloud Functions deployment issue. Google Cloud Functions doesn't see the installed module in source code(main.py, requirements.txt)

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions

Can someone help me with deploying a Google Cloud Function? I'm facing an issue while trying to deploy it.

I encountered an error stating that my function couldn't find the 'firebase_admin' module, even though it was included in the requirements.txt file. I'm not sure what might be causing this problem.

Here are some relevant details:

- [Log information: ]

```
{
  "protoPayload": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog",
    "status": {
      "code": 3,
      "message": "Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in the user code. Error message: Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/layers/google.python.pip/pip/bin/functions-framework\", line 8, in <module>\n    sys.exit(_cli())\n  File \"/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py\", line 1130, in __call__\n    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)\n  File \"/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py\", line 1055, in main\n    rv = self.invoke(ctx)\n  File \"/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py\", line 1404, in invoke\n    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)\n  File \"/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py\", line 760, in invoke\n    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)\n  File \"/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/functions_framework/_cli.py\", line 36, in _cli\n    app = create_app(target, source, signature_type)\n  File \"/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/functions_framework/__init__.py\", line 356, in create_app\n    spec.loader.exec_module(source_module)\n  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>\", line 850, in exec_module\n  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed\n  File \"/workspace/main.py\", line 15, in <module>\n    import firebase_admin\nModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'firebase_admin'. Please visit https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting for in-depth troubleshooting documentation."
    },
    "authenticationInfo": {
      "principalEmail": "***.com"
    },
    "serviceName": "cloudfunctions.googleapis.com",
    "methodName": "google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.UpdateFunction",
    "resourceName": "projects/***/locations/europe-west1/functions/***"
  },
  "insertId": "***",
  "resource": {
    "type": "cloud_function",
    "labels": {
      "region": "europe-west1",
      "function_name": "***",
      "project_id": "***"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2023-06-29T06:05:33.456946Z",
  "severity": "ERROR",
  "logName": "projects/***/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity",
  "operation": {
    "id": "operations/Z2Vyby1kZXYvZXVyb3BlLXdlc3QxL2Nsb3VkX2Z1bmN0aW9uX2dlcm9fY29uZmlndXJhdGlvbi9FT3VBbW1wSURVQQ",
    "producer": "cloudfunctions.googleapis.com",
    "last": true
  },
  "receiveTimestamp": "2023-06-29T06:05:33.626908359Z"
}
```

- [main.py]

```py
/// 15th line
import firebase_admin
```

- [requirements.txt]

```
anyio==3.6.2
attrs==23.1.0
blinker==1.6.2
CacheControl==0.13.1
cachetools==5.3.1
cairocffi==1.5.1
CairoSVG==2.7.0
cattrs==23.1.2
cdktf==0.17.0
certifi==2023.5.7
cffi==1.15.1
charset-normalizer==3.1.0
click==8.1.3
cloudevents==1.9.0
constructs==10.2.60
cryptography==41.0.1
cssselect2==0.7.0
DateTime==5.1
defusedxml==0.7.1
deprecation==2.1.0
exceptiongroup==1.1.1
fastapi==0.95.2
firebase-admin==6.1.0
Flask==2.3.2
functions-framework==3.4.0
google-api-core==2.11.0
google-api-python-client==2.90.0
google-auth==2.19.0
google-auth-httplib2==0.1.0
google-cloud-core==2.3.2
google-cloud-firestore==2.11.1
google-cloud-storage==2.9.0
google-crc32c==1.5.0
google-resumable-media==2.5.0
googleapis-common-protos==1.59.0
grpcio==1.54.2
grpcio-status==1.54.2
gunicorn==20.1.0
h11==0.14.0
html5lib==1.1
httplib2==0.22.0
idna==3.4
importlib-metadata==6.6.0
importlib-resources==5.12.0
itsdangerous==2.1.2
Jinja2==3.1.2
jsii==1.84.0
MarkupSafe==2.1.2
msgpack==1.0.5
packaging==23.1
Pillow==9.5.0
proto-plus==1.22.2
protobuf==4.23.2
publication==0.0.3
pyasn1==0.5.0
pyasn1-modules==0.3.0
pycparser==2.21
pydantic==1.10.8
PyJWT==2.7.0
pyparsing==3.1.0
pyphen==0.14.0
python-dateutil==2.8.2
python-dotenv==1.0.0
pytz==2023.3
requests==2.31.0
rsa==4.9
six==1.16.0
sniffio==1.3.0
starlette==0.27.0
tinycss2==1.2.1
typeguard==2.13.3
typing_extensions==4.6.1
uritemplate==4.1.1
urllib3==1.26.16
uvicorn==0.22.0
watchdog==3.0.0
WeasyPrint==52.4
webencodings==0.5.1
Werkzeug==2.3.4
zipp==3.15.0
zope.interface==6.0
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

I tried to deploy my function in Google Cloud Functions.